# ISPs hijacking DNS errors on the web

Tags: website, isp, hijack

I've noticed that ISPs have started hijacking DNS errors and show their own error pages instead (complete with annoying graphics and ads). Is there any way to fix this, or are they doing it on their network outside of my control?

Note that I've not installed any of their software, and it is very much network dependent. I've seen it with Verizon FiOS and Comcast.

Comment: Are you seeing this consistently with FiOS and Comcast?

Comment: Yes. At work we have FiOS, and all of the computers see FiOS errors. I get Comcast errors at home where we have Comcast (and I've never installed any Comcast software).

Comment: Time Warner Road Runner is doing this again.  Its bad enough they are a monopoly and I dont get to choose another cable internet / television provider but to also hijack 404's?  FAIL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can opt out of Comcast's DNS hijacking](https://dns-opt-out.comcast.net/)

[Verizon simply instructs you to change your DNS server](http://www.verizon.net/central/vzc.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=vzc_help_contentDisplay&case=dns_assist)

EDIT: That was very odd, I could not for the life of me get that VZ link to work, so I did a tinyurl and that works.

Comment: The Verizon link is giving me a blank page. But +1 for the Comcast link.

Comment: @musicfreak: Try it again

Comment: You can opt out of Time-Warner's hijacking as well.  I assume it records your modem's MAC in a whitelist. (blacklist?)

Answer (score 5):

Google have just released [public DNS](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/introducing-google-public-dns.html) - just set your DNS servers to

```
8.8.8.8
```

and

```
8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way is probably to put [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com)'s IPs in your router as its DNS server-

208.67.222.222

208.67.220.220

You should then see [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com)'s page instead of your ISP's. (I would trust OpenDNS more!)

(You can also do this directly on your computer, however you may loose the ability to access other computers on your lan via their FQDN / Computer name)

Other than that, the only solution I can think of is setting up your own DNS server that has no recursion apart from the root servers - but I don't think you would want to do this.

Comment: Level3 also provides open DNS servers (not part of the OpenDNS project).  If you want to mix, you could also add one or more of 4.2.2.1, 4.2.2.2, 4.2.2.3, and 4.2.2.4.  The advantage is that if one IP block goes down, the other DNS server will keep working.

I also like the 4.2.2.x servers because it's really easy to remember their addresses.  :)

Comment: it must be noted that opendns does dns hijacking as well. was very disappointed to find this out.

Comment: Apparently this can be turned off. Doing so also turns off some of the content filtering (i.e. phish protection and such) too, though which is only an issue if those features are important to you.

Answer (score 1):

For FiOS, you can just change the last octet of the Verizon-supplied DNS server from 12 to 14.

If you are using OpenDNS, you can to create a (free) account and opt out of the error page.